# Referenecement with JavaScript

Tags: jsf

Do you think this kind of code enjoy google ?

```
<form id="j_id29" name="j_id29" method="post" action="/stockradio/radio.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id29" value="j_id29" />
<table class="dr-table rich-table " id="j_id29:j_id30" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><colgroup span="1"></colgroup><thead class="dr-table-thead"><tr class="dr-table-header rich-table-header  "><th class="dr-table-headercell rich-table-headercell  " colspan="1" scope="colgroup">Sorting Example</th></tr><tr class="dr-table-subheader rich-table-subheader "><th class="dr-table-subheadercell rich-table-subheadercell  " scope="col" id="j_id29:j_id30:j_id32header" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('_viewRoot','j_id29',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id29:j_id30','parameters':{'fsp':'j_id29:j_id30:j_id32','j_id29:j_id30':'fsp'} ,'actionUrl':'/stockradio/radio.jsf'} )" style="cursor: pointer;"><div id="j_id29:j_id30:j_id32header:sortDiv"><span class="dr-table-sortable-header">State Name<img src="/stockradio/a4j/g/3_3_1.GAorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.iconimages.DataTableIconSortNone/DATB/eAFjYGD4!!8!AAYAAv4_.jsf" alt="" width="15" height="15" class="dr-table-header-sort-img rich-sort-icon" /></span></div></th></tr></thead><tfoot><tr class="dr-table-footer rich-table-footer  "><td class="dr-table-footercell rich-table-footercell  " colspan="1" scope="colgroup"><div class="dr-dscr rich-datascr " id="j_id29:j_id30:ds" style=" " align="center"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="dr-dscr-t rich-dtascroller-table " id="j_id29:j_id30:ds_table" style="text-align:center"><tbody><tr><td class="dr-dscr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button-dsbld dr-dscr-button rich-datascr-button">&#171;&#171;</td><td class="dr-dscr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button-dsbld dr-dscr-button rich-datascr-button">&#171;</td><td class="dr-dscr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button-dsbld dr-dscr-button rich-datascr-button"></td><td class="dr-dscr-act rich-datascr-act ">1</td><td class="dr-dscr-inact rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '2'});">2</td><td class=" dr-dscr-button rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'next'});"></td><td class=" dr-dscr-button rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'fastforward'});">&#187;</td><td class=" dr-dscr-button rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'last'});">&#187;&#187;</td></tr></tbody></table><script type="text/javascript">new Richfaces.Datascroller('j_id29:j_id30:ds', function(event){A4J.AJAX.Submit('_viewRoot','j_id29',event,{'ignoreDupResponses':true,'implicitEventsQueue':'j_id29:j_id30:ds','similarityGroupingId':'j_id29:j_id30:ds','parameters':{'ajaxSingle':'j_id29:j_id30:ds','j_id29:j_id30:ds':event.memo.page} ,'actionUrl':'/stockradio/radio.jsf'} ); return false;});</script></div></td></tr></tfoot><tbody id="j_id29:j_id30:tb"><tr class="dr-table-row rich-table-row dr-table-firstrow rich-table-firstrow "><td class="dr-table-cell rich-table-cell center " id="j_id29:j_id30:0:j_id32"> 

     <b>MY KEY WORD2</b>

</td></tr><tr class="dr-table-row rich-table-row "><td class="dr-table-cell rich-table-cell center " id="j_id29:j_id30:1:j_id32">

     <b>MY KEY WORD1</b>

</td></tr></tbody></table><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id1" />
</form>
```

! This html was generated by the "rich:dataTable" JSF component who create this table. Moreover this component create JavaScript interation as "order by".

I think it's better to use TABLE balise for google. No ?

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm... well, if I'm reading the question right (which is tricky), I guess you're saying that the above code is bad because Google will only see and index the words “MY KEY WORD2” and “MY KEY WORD1”, and not all the content that presumably is going to get fetched into the page from the Richfaces.Datascroller through AJAX.

In which case, yes! You're right!

Comment: I agree - although I'd add - that's not any different from most any other Ajax application.